# Firebase how to implement post feature with multiple images in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I would like to implement function like instagram  that user can post with multiple images. I have tableviewcell and on the tableviewcell, there is collectionviewcell to display images.

Here is my firebase structure

```
 "Post": {
    "uid": {
      "Text": "some text",
      "Date": "some date",
      "images": {
         autoID1: url1,
         autoID2: url2
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is my model. Am I initializing properly?

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


struct Post {

    var Text: String!
    var Date: String!
    var images: String?

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot){

    for child in snapshot.children{
        key = snapshot.key
        ref = snapshot.ref
        Text = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Text"] as! String
        Date = (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Date"] as? String
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        images = snap.value as! String   
    }
  }
}
```

then I would like to fetch like this so that latest post appear on top. but problem is that user don't pick images every time. sometimes, they only post some text, in that case app will crush.

```
var postsArray = [Post]()

func fetchPosts(){

    dataBaseRef.child("Post").child(uid!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var results = [Post]()

        for post in snapshot.children {

        let post = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)

            results.append(post)
        }

        self.usersArray = results.sorted(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in
            u1.Date > u2.Date
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

My question is how to create feature that latest post comes on top and if no images picked, only text and date observed and display on the tableviewcell?

Also, how should I configure the cell when it comes to display multiple images on collection view? I implemented Text and Date but I'm struggling with images.

```
func configureCell(post: Post){

        self.TextLabel.text = post.Text
        self.DateLabel.text = post.Date
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postsCell", for: indexPath) as! PostsTableViewCell

        cell.configureCell(post: postsArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

//how to configure cell?
    import UIKit
    import Firebase

    class PostCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

        @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

        var storageRef: Storage {
            return Storage.storage()
        }

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension to Firebase's `DataSnapshot` (aka. `FIRDataSnapshot`) that will help converting values from a snapshot into the most convenient types for your classes. In the specific case of the date, I am assuming you are storing them as milliseconds using `Firebase.ServerValue`.

```
extension DataSnapshot {
    func child(_ pathString: String) -> DataSnapshot { 
        return childSnapshot(forPath: pathString)
    }
    var snapshots: [DataSnapshot] {
        return children.allObjects.flatMap({ $0 as? DataSnapshot })
    }
    var date: Date? { return double.flatMap({ $0 / 1000 }) }
    var double: Double? { return value as? Double }
    var string: String? { return value as? String }
    var url: URL? { return string.flatMap({ URL(string: $0) }) }
    var urls: [URL] { return snapshots.flatMap({ $0.url }) }
}
```

You can now initialise a `Post` with a snapshot and have the properties conveniently casted to the right type without crashing if they're not there. This way you have less to think about when you are configuring cells with the data.

```
struct Post {

    // MARK: Properties

    let snapshot: DataSnapshot

    var created: Date!
    var images: [URL]?
    var text: String!

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        self.snapshot = snapshot
        self.created = snapshot.child("created").date
        self.images = snapshot.child("images").urls
        self.text = snapshot.child("text").string
    }
}
```

Configuring the cell to show an image will be a lot easier if you store the `downloadURL` of the images instead of a storage reference. When you pass the post to the table view cell, it just needs to tell a collection view how many URLs it has – then for each cell at an indexPath, you configure it with the corresponding URL in the post's images array.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that out!!

Comment: @Callam where did you find snapshot.`child` ? I don't see such property in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value

Comment: Oopsy, my mistake – that's a custom extension.

Answer (score 0):

if you import Firebase, there is no need to import also FirebaseDatabase.
But the images should be (snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary)["Images"] as! [String: String]. You can use a for loop to get the values out of that dictionary.
I would recommend force unwrapping everything though, if you always have text and date, use a guard let with early escape for them, and an if let for the images.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that out!!