# Firebase create model which has optional values in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to create model which has optional values.
I implemented `flatmap` to achieve that. node look like this and imageUrl does not exist everytime like so.

```
"Post": {
    "uid": {
　　　"autoid"{
       "Text": "some text",
       "Date": "some date",
       "imageUrl": {
         autoID1: url1,
         autoID2: url2
      }
     },
    "autoid"{
      "Text": "some text",
      "Date": "some date"
     } 
    }
  }
```

I created a model here

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

extension  DataSnapshot {
    var snapshots: [DataSnapshot] {
        return children.allObjects.flatMap({ $0 as? DataSnapshot })
    }
    var string: String? { return value as? String }
    var url: URL? { return string.flatMap({ URL(string: $0) }) }
    var urls: [URL] { return snapshots.flatMap({ $0.url }) }
}

struct Post {

    let snapshot: DataSnapshot?

    var Date: String!
    var imageUrl: [URL]?
    var Text: String!

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        self.snapshot = snapshot
        self.Date = snapshot.child["Date"].string
        self.imageUrl = snapshot.child["imageUrl"].urls
        self.Text = snapshot.child["Text"].string
    }
}
```

but inside `init`, error says

> Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'child'

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Also is this right way to create function like twitter post with multiple images and sometimes images are none, only text displayed.

Comment: DataSnapshot doesn't have the member child, https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value. So to be able to extract something from the DataSnapshot, you might use this idea:

`if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
  self.Date = value["Date"] as? String ?? ""
}`

Comment: Thank you for the comment but this method would return nothing right? for example, there are 5 posts and one of them don't have some value, then posts to show will be nothing because values don't match up with model object. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The point is `child``doesn't exist, then you can't compile, because it's a custom extension you copied from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47844462/2450755, check the last comments in that answer, am I wrong?

Comment: I saw that and error was gone but didn't get what I expected. Your method will work perfectly for "Date" and "Text". However how can I initialize imageUrl? Since it's another child and key is autoid so you can't cast like value["autoid"] right?

Comment: The approach is the same, just need to dig a bit more. If you tell me exactly what is after `imageUrl`, because the text above is not a valid JSON. I may argue that "imageUrl": { autoID1: url1, autoID2: url2 } might be a sub dictionary, but since the implementation in the other post, was managing it as array, I can't say exactly. That's why I asked you, in another comment below, to fix the JSON first (dictionary? / array?), and then I will be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I really appreciate it. I updated the photo above would you take a look at it?

Comment: for getting the content of `tweetImageUrl`, try this: 
`var daibakuUrls = [URL]()
if let urls = value["tweetImageUrl"] as? [String] {
  for url in urls {
     if let finalUrl = URL(string: url) {
        daibakuUrls.append(finalUrl)
     }
  }
}
print(daibakuUrls)`

Comment: I tried and it went through without crash but I didn't get what I expected. If you don't mind, can we continue this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161662/discussion-between-daibaku-and-andrea-mugnaini).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSnapshot` doesn't have the member `child`, doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value).
So to be able to extract something from the `DataSnapshot`, you might use this idea:

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
  self.Date = value["Date"] as? String ?? ""
  self.Text = value.child["Text"] as? String ?? ""

  // extracting the urls
  if let urls = value.child["tweetImageUrl"] as? [String:String] {
    self.imageUrl = urls.flatMap { k,v in URL(string:v) }
  }
}
```

**Note that**:
`flatMap` is awesome because provide the possibility to skip automatically all the iterations that are returning an optional value.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I know how to cast like so but when it comes to using flatmap,also imageurl have multiple values so I can't figure out. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: might you fix the JSON above? is not valid